# Retrofit with OkHTTP not set Content-Type with @FormUrlEncoded

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to implement auth via `x-www-form-urlencoded` with Retrofit 2 on Android but faced a problem, that Header `Content-Type` not set with `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation, as well as I'm trying to set it manually, but when I'm setting it with a typo like `Cotent-Type` it works correctly and I can see it in headers.

Retrofit version: 2.4.0

So my question: why `@FormUrlEncoded` not set a content type as well as `@Header` annotation or what can remove it from headers.

My request:

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("account/login")
   Single<LoginResponse> login(@Field("memberId") String memberId,
                                    @Field("pin") String pin);
```

OkHTTP/Retrofit provider with interceptors:

```
    @Singleton
@Provides
Retrofit provideRetrofit(final OkHttpClient client, final Moshi moshi) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Configuration.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

    @Provides
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(@AppContext final Context context) {
    final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .followRedirects(true)
            .followSslRedirects(true)
            .addInterceptor(createLanguageInterceptor(context));

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        builder.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
    }

    return builder.build();
}

Interceptor createLanguageInterceptor(@AppContext final Context context) {
    Locale current = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    return chain -> {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        builder.addHeader("Accept-Language", current.getLanguage());
        Request request = builder.build();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    };
}
```

As a workaround, I've implemented the following interceptor:

```
Interceptor createHeaderTransformationInterceptor() {
    return chain -> {
        final Request request = chain.request();
        String dataType = request.header("Data-Type");
        final Request resultRequest = dataType == null
                ? request
                : chain.request().newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("Data-Type")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", dataType)
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(resultRequest);
    };
}
```

and it works fine with the following annotation:

```
@Headers({"Data-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

**UPD:** *the reason that my interceptor didn't see that is in a place where the content type is stored. The right way to see that header in an interceptor*:

```
    if (requestBody.contentType() != null) {
      logger.log("Content-Type: " + requestBody.contentType());
    }
    if (requestBody.contentLength() != -1) {
      logger.log("Content-Length: " + requestBody.contentLength());
    }
```

Comment: By @FormUrlEncoded Annotation "Content-Type : FormURLEncoded " automatically added by retrofit.

Use "interceptor" and log your result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this Request

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("account/login")
Single<LoginResponse> login(@Field("memberId") String memberId,
                                        @Field("pin") String pin);
```

method `@POST` and `@FormUrlEncoded` automatic add

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in header you can check in log by

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();
```

it print all log in verbose mode

Comment: Thanks.
My `LoggingInterceptor` didn't see that.