# My code gives 403 response in retrofit android, though the url works fine in postman

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am pulling json data from a url. It works fine in postman, but in android retrofit it gives 403 response, please help

```
public interface RestAPIService {

    String BASE_URL = "https://www.abercrombie.com/";

    // endpoint to retrieve arraylist for loading in the recyclerview in main activity
    @GET("anf/nativeapp/qa/codetest/codeTest_exploreData.json")
    Call<ArrayList<Promotion>> getPromotions();
}
```

Comment: in post man, which code you received?

Comment: Error description, given by retrofit?

Comment: are you missing and header parameters?

Comment: Everything looking fine but you can check by reference link [Retrofit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846072/retrofit-with-okhttp-not-set-content-type-with-formurlencoded/53846641#53846641)

Comment: how are you initializing retrofit ?

Comment: Every time I hear something like this it's because by default postman adds some headers that retrofit doesn't. Sometimes, the server cannot handle requests without these headers and behaves differently. I'd recommend checking these and see if there's any that would cause this issue if missing.

Comment: 403 error means The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

Comment: In post man I received success code 200 OK, I don't know of any header parameters, there is no authentication required

Comment: What kind of headers are possible, please share any resource on this

Comment: @DivyanshuSonwani I have added the interceptor but still the same, can you please help i need to submit this assignment, I have spent hours on this

Answer (score 1):

It's because the route may require the token authentication from headers which you may be missing.

Comment: Can you give more information on how to fix it. I have never worked with this kind of problem before